# Why does my redirect fail to load the expected component?

Tags: angular, angular-router

I have an Angular application with a redirect in place within the routing module to handle old urls, however the redirect is not hitting the expected routes, and instead falls through to the wildcard route. Below is a simplified example of the issue:

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'old',
        redirectTo: '..'
    },
    {
        path: 'a',
    component: AComponent
    },
    {
        path: 'b',
    component: BComponent
    },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full' }
];
```

I'm expecting `/old/a` to redirect to `/a` and `old/b` to redirect to `/b`. This doesn't happen.

Instead, the URL in the browser URL bar is correctly rewritten, but Angular loads the `PageNotFoundComponent`. If I then manually refresh the page, the correct component loads.

I've tried enabling route tracing, and the rewrite seems to be applied as expected:

```
NavigationEnd(id: 1, url: '/old/a', urlAfterRedirects: '/../a')
```

**Why does the redirect not result in the expected components being loaded, and how do I ensure that it will?**

**Edit:** Stackblitz showing the problem:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1gt7c
Navigate to `old/a` and notice that the URL is correctly rewritten to `/a`, but the "Page not found" message is shown instead of "A works!"

Comment: You can only redirect to existing paths in your application..?

Comment: The paths do exist

Comment: I've added a stackblitz which shows the problem in action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameters: instead of

```
    {
        path: 'old',
        redirectTo: '..',
    },
```

go

```
    {
        path: 'old/:child',
        redirectTo: ':child',
    },
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e1gt7c-twawde?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts